# How to present a View Controller modally from top just like dismiss style?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

How to present a View Controller modally from top? I want to present my View Controller just like dismiss style... I already tried CATransition but it is not giving me the same animation duration. Any help?

The CATransition approach:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DownloadAudio") as! DownloadAudioViewController 

let transition = CATransition() 
transition.duration = 0.25 
transition.type = kCATransitionPush 
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom 
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseO‌​ut) 

view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition) 
present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code with the approach with the CATransition? The duration can be adjusted.

Comment: `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DownloadAudio") as! DownloadAudioViewController
        
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.25
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: The thing is, I want to present it exactly like dismiss style...

Comment: Im sorry, but I don't understand. The dismiss style is that the view goes **out** of screen from the bottom edge. How can you **show** something by sending it out of screen? Maybe you mean you want to controller to be shown from the top of the screen going down?

Comment: @Giuseppe Lanza I want my controller to go down when I click on a button. just like when I click on dismiss button it goes down. I hope it's clear. I don't know how to make it more clear, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom presentation by creating an object, like this one, that vends present and dismiss animation objects:

```
class PresentationObjectVendor: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return CustomDropPresentAnimator()
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return CustomDropDismissAnimator()
    }

}
```

and then creating those animation objects, like these:

```
// present animator
class CustomDropPresentAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        // return a time interval
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // perform animations
    }

}

// dismiss animator
class CustomDropDismissAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        // return a time interval
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // perform animations
    }

}
```